# merge multiple txt files

Tags: awk, perl, join, merge

I have multiple txt files, 3 of them are like:

file1:

```
sample  input filtered
5809378   1      2
5811151   3      4
5811237   5      6
```

file2:

```
sample  chi tri
5809378  7   8
5811151      
5811237  9   10
```

file3:

```
sample   bra  doe
5809378  11 
5811151        12
5811237  13    14
```

I want to merge these 3 files into 1 based on the first column: sample ID, so the output would look like:

```
sample  input  filters  chi  tri   bra   doe
5809378    1     2      7     8     11     0
5811151    3     4      0     0     0     12
5811237    5     6      9     10    13    14
```

Notice that if there is no Corresponding data, there must be a zero, or in the worst case, an empty tab.

I have tried awk and join, and couldn't;t find a best solution. Anyone has any idea?

Comment: It is good practice to explictly show what you did instead of just mentioning the tools. Is your input sorted and if not, does it matter if it was?

Answer (score 0):

The file3 is not totally correct from my point of view, because line

`5811151        12`

may have number "12" in second or third column, depending on how we read the file (a columns separator is not defined and not the same everywhere).

Anyway.

```
a=$(cat file1|awk '{if($2==""){$2="0"};if($3==""){$3="0"}; print $1,$2,$3}'|sort);
for f in file2 file3; do
    b=$(cat $f|awk '{if($2==""){$2="0"};if($3==""){$3="0"}; print $1,$2,$3}'|sort);
    a=$(join -j 1 <(echo "${a}") <(echo "${b}"));
done;
echo "${a}"|sort -n
```

output is

```
sample input filtered chi tri bra doe
5809378 1 2 7 8 11 0
5811151 3 4 0 0 12 0
5811237 5 6 9 10 13 14
```

So, we

***1) Each taken file transformed***

`cat file|awk '{if($2==""){$2="0"};if($3==""){$3="0"}; print $1,$2,$3}'|sort`

to replace missing numbers with '0' and sort lines.

***2) In a cycle we take a next file and merge it to previous result***

`join -j 1 file_current file_next`

so the line "for f in file2 file3; do" may be changed to include more files, for example "for f in file2 file3 file4 file5 file6; do".

***3) Print the result, sorted according to string numerical value*** (to order and to print column names first). Also we can format the output here if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your files have tab-separated columns (So you can tell which columns are empty in cases like the third line of your `file3`), and are sorted on the first column like your samples, a bash script like so:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

function fixup() { # Add 0's to blank columns
    awk -v cols="$2" 'BEGIN { FS = OFS = "\t" }
                      { for (i = 1; i <= cols; i++)
                         if ($i == "") $i = 0
                      } 1' "$1"
}

join --header -t$'\t' -j1 \
     <(join --header -t$'\t' -j1 <(fixup "$1" 3) \
                                 <(fixup "$2" 3)) \
     <(fixup "$3" 3)
```

will do it:

```
$ ./combine file1 file2 file3
sample  input   filtered        chi     tri     bra     doe
5809378 1       2       7       8       11      0
5811151 3       4       0       0       0       12
5811237 5       6       9       10      13      14
```

(Does require the GNU coreutils version of `join`).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your starting files are tab delimited, and that the empty fields are still tab separated, you could zero fill the missing columns with awk, like:

```
awk -F'     ' '!$2{$2=0}!$3{$3=0}{print}' file1 > file1-n
awk -F'     ' '!$2{$2=0}!$3{$3=0}{print}' file2 > file3-n
awk -F'     ' '!$2{$2=0}!$3{$3=0}{print}' file3 > file3-n
```

That's `awk -F '<TAB>'`, to be clear.  Then you could use paste to merge them, with another awk to filter the unneeded columns:

```
bash-$ paste file1-n file2-n file3-n | awk {'print $1, $2, $3, $5, $6, $8, $9'}
sample input filtered chi tri bra doe
5809378 1 2 7 8 11 0
5811151 3 4 0 0 0 12
5811237 5 6 9 10 13 14
```

Or space the columns if human readability is important:

```
bash-$ paste file1-n file2-n file3-n | awk {'printf "%-7s %-5s %-8s %-3s %-3s %-3s %-3s\n", $1, $2, $3, $5, $6, $8, $9'}
sample  input filtered chi tri bra doe
5809378 1     2        7   8   11  0
5811151 3     4        0   0   0   12
5811237 5     6        9   10  13  14
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative, assuming a `tab` delimiter

First fix the files by inserting a `0` between double `tab`s or where the line ends `$` without either text (i.e. it's a title) or a number `[^[:alnum:]]`

```
TAB=$'\t'; sed -Ei "s/([^[:alnum:]]|${TAB})($|${TAB})/\10\2/g" file*
```

Then just `join` them

```
join --header file2 file3 | join --header file1 - | column -t
```

Output

```
sample   input  filtered  chi  tri  bra  doe
5809378  1      2         7    8    11   0
5811151  3      4         0    0    0    12
5811237  5      6         9    10   13   14
```